# Including header file .h in C program file and I got an error file not exist

Tags: c, cygwin

Using a Cygwin-ready makefile, I add to existing C code a new header file. But when I compile, I get an error that the header file I include does not exist.

```
#include "freefare_internal.h"
```

and I tried to include the path also:

```
#include "../Application/freefare_internal.h"
```

How can I get the compiler to find the header?

Comment: In which directory your program (.c file) and header file (.h) located?

Comment: As well as knowing which directory your source code and header file are in (and the directory where the compilation is run), it would probably be sensible to show the command line that compiles the code.  The general solution is normally to add `-I /path/to/directory` where the directory contains the `freefare_internal.h` header.  Also, based on the header file name, you should probably not include `freefare_internal.h` in your code unless your code is part of the FreeFare package; it is marked 'internal' and should be left unused — unless there's explicit documentation that suggests using it.

Comment: I am using a cygwin and there is an exist make file for the application I am trying to modify there is no CFLAG there I found another CC_FLAGS     = -DUSE_LUFA_CONFIG_HEADER -DBUILD_DATE=$(BUILD_DATE) $(SETTINGS) but I don't know if this can be the same and I can modify it to have the path of the heathers files